# Keyboard shortcut for "Show Package Contents"

Tags: macos, keyboard

I know you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open a folder, however when you do that on an application it opens the application.

Is it possible to either make <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> always show the contents or is there another shortcut for that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I suggest that you create a custom Finder shortcut in **System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts → <kbd>+</kbd>**.

This way you can open packages with <kbd>⌥</kbd> as a modifier key.

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open folders
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open packages

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Another Wow!, this is possibly the single smallest/tiny-but-awesome reasons why OSX > windows (most of the time anyway)

Comment: Then it is OSX ≥ Windows, no? ;P (I couldn't help it…)

Comment: Sorry for double comments, but this solution isn't working for me. (OS X 10.8) I think that this solution only works if it can be found in the menu.

Comment: (On OS X Lion 10.8.5) I do not have the "Show Package Contents" item menu in my Finder's Finder menu. I could add one shortcut after adding the action item in the toolbar. So right-click on the toolbar, select "Customize toolbar...", add the "action" item to the toolbar, then System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts to assign the keyboard shortcut you want. HTH

Comment: It works for me. (On Yosemite, I didn't need to do anything other than what's in the original answer )

Comment: Problem is that ⌘ + ↓ does the same thing for folders as ⌘ + O does e.g. two hotkeys serving the same purpose but it is impossible to assign more than one hotkey for a given command for a given application.

Comment: @Jonathan. I would agree if I could rename files and folders under a "save dialog window". Until then, no. OSX < Windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a single keystroke to open regular items and regular folders, but show package contents for packages (including Applications), you can turn to Automator.

Create a new **Service** in Automator.

The service receives **files or folders** in **Finder.app**.

The first action is **Run AppleScript**. Here is the script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set my_output to {}
    repeat with oneItem in input
        if package folder of (info for oneItem as alias) then
            try
                tell application "Finder" to open folder ((oneItem as text) & "Contents")
            end try
        else
            set my_output to my_output & oneItem
        end if
    end repeat
    if ((count my_output) is 0) then
        error number -128
    end if
    return my_output
end run
```

The second action is **Open Finder Items**

Save your service. I called mine `BetterOpen`.

Then, go to **System Preferences** » **Keyboard** » **Keyboard Shortcuts** » **Services** and assign a keystroke to the service. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to reclaim shortcuts already claimed by the Finder, so you may have to pick a keystroke other than <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>.

If you want to open the package in the same window, replace the line

```
 tell application "Finder" to open folder ((oneItem as text) & "Contents")
```

with

```
 tell application "Finder" to set target of window 1 to ((oneItem as text) & "Contents")
```

Answer (score -2):

Under snow leopard, I found the simplest way was to use SAVE A COPY as iwork 08. then right click to and the show package content option will be available.

Comment: This does no answer the users question. They want to show package contents using a keyboard command, not using iWork '08. That relies on proprietary software that is now 5 years old.