# How to make KEXT files open with Finder

Tags: macos, finder, kernel-extensions

I frequently edit files inside of kernel extension (.KEXT) files on OS X.  To do this, I have to right-click and "Show Package Contents".  To save time, I would like to simply double-click the package and have it open with Finder.
Ideally, Finder would show the full folder hierarchy in column view.  Currently, when I show the package contents, the folder hierarchy is "reset" with the package as root.  As you can see in this screenshot, there is no horizontal scrollbar, so I can't quickly traverse up the hierarchy as I could in a normal directory tree.  I'm working in Sierra, but this question could apply to any recent version of OS X.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Automator Service using the setting in the image below.

[image]

Then assign it a keyboard shortcut in: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services

I assigned it: <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

**Code for Run Shell Script:**

```
for f in "$@"
do
    fn="$(basename "$f")"
    ext="${fn##*.}"
    if [[ $ext == kext ]]; then
        open "$f/Contents"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of a way to do it with a mouse double-click instead of keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @Elliott, I would not do it because, in order for that to happen the `.kext` extension would have to be registered with Launch Services as to what App is to open it and by default **Open with:** for the `.kext` extension is **Not applicable** and IMO shouldn't be changed as it may have unintended consequences in doing so. I'd use the method in my answer or do nothing at all. BTW, By making this a Service, you can right-click the KEXT and select Open KEXT from the Services section of the Context Menu in Finder. Continued in next comment...

Comment: It's not as easy as a double-click but it all mouse movements and doesn't have the unintended consequences jeopardy associated with registering the extension to respond to a double-click.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to make packages simply behave like regular folders in macOS. However, to make your life a bit easier, you may want to take a look at [this similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/44295/12285) — there you can find instructions for adding a keyboard shortcut to Show Package Contents, and if you're willing to do a bit more work, creating an Automator action to determine which to do automatically.